# how to get Jmeter Session local storage into Jmeter Webdriver sample using Java or Groovy language

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, webdriver, performance-testing

[image]I have to extract a value of forterToken from localstorage and want to use it in a payload variable. Trying webdriver sample in JMeter.  I have found the code to extract this value using Javascript but in JMeter webdriver Javascipt langauage is not appearing. Can anyone help me out to provide me this code in Java or Groovy? Becasue Webdriver has these languages option only Java/Groovy/bsh/jexl.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have a very interesting approach to "writing" the code.

Whatever, no matter of the language which is being used in any case you will have to call [executeScript() function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

in case of Groovy it would be something like:

```
WDS.browser.executeScript('return window.localStorage.getItem("forterToken ");')
```

Demo:

[image]

[image]

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)